# Mapbox GL JS Geocoding to only reference Tileset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm using Mapbox's Geocoding (search box) and was wondering if there's a way that it would only reference my Tileset data rather than the generic global address search?  Looks like Mapbox has a "[Supplement geocoding search results from another data source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-local-geocoder/)", however the example is referencing geographic coordinates rather than addressing.  So I'm still not sure if this is possible?

Basically I want to enter an address in the Geocoding search box and to have a particular polygon selected from my dataset on the map.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/273583/115

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to shows how to supplement search results with a local source, not a remote source in the https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder.

Currently Mapbox doesn't provide a Geocoding API against your own data however depending on how large your dataset is (and assuming it's a Mapbox Dataset and not just a Mapbox Tileset) you could use the Datasets API to read in every feature into the client with https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js/blob/master/API.md#listfeatures and use the results of that to power the mapbox-gl-geocoder search like https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-local-geocoder/

Comment: Thanks so much for responding.  I've uploaded my data as a Mapbox Dataset then was prompted to convert it to a Tileset, so basically I have both? Your recommendation is to use the coding from GITHub's List Features then run Mapbox's Geocoder to it taken that the size of the data isn't too great? Sorry, I'm just struggling with all the documentation out there and trying to make sense of it all and what will work best in my situation.  My data set is just a couple MB's right now but will drastically increase in time.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You have a few options... If the data could grow to more than a few MB's I would suggest creating your own JSON file with the search query and bbox and use that in gl-geocoder. I understand an example would be easier, but it might be a few days before I have time to put one together.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew, any example would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: thanks a lot for down voting me...is that a slap on the hand for accidentally cross posting?